# PHP - Errors with get_headers and SSL

Tags: php, get-headers

This is my code

```
$url = 'http://www.wikipedia.com';  // URL WITH HTTP
$hurl = str_replace("http", "https", $url); // URL WITH HTTPS

$urlheads = get_headers($url, 1);   
$surlheads = get_headers($hurl, 1);     
$urlx = false;
$surlx = false;

foreach ($urlheads as $name => $value) 
{
    if ($name === 'Location') 
    {
        $urlx=$value;   
    }
    else{

    }
}
print_r($urlx);
```

And this is error I'm getting:

```
Warning: get_headers(): Peer certificate CN=`*.wikipedia.org' did not match expected CN=`www.wikipedia.com' in....

Warning: get_headers(): Failed to enable crypto in....

Warning: get_headers(https://www.wikipedia.com): failed to open stream:     operation failed in .....
Array ( [0] => http://www.wikipedia.org/ [1] => https://www.wikipedia.org/ )
```

Why is this happening and what is proper way to get headers from https page without errors (without curl). Also, when I try on some other https site everything is ok

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue is down to the server certificate being presented as a wildcard `*` so it can allow all sub-domains under the same certificate, but for some strange reason the wildcard `*` is used literally during the SSL verify leading to failure. To get around this, use `stream_context_set_default()` to set the SSL verification as `false`.

```
stream_context_set_default( [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
]);

$url = 'https://www.wikipedia.com';  // URL WITH HTTPS

$headers = get_headers($url, 1);

var_dump($headers);
```

**Output**

```
array(25) {
    [0] => string(30)
    "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ["Date"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(29)
        "Sun, 27 Nov 2016 15:44:44 GMT" [1] => string(29)
        "Sun, 27 Nov 2016 15:44:44 GMT"
    }["Content-Type"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(29)
        "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" [1] => string(9)
        "text/html"
    }["Content-Length"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(3)
        "234" [1] => string(5)
        "80740"
    }["Connection"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(5)
        "close" [1] => string(5)
        "close"
    }["Server"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(18)
        "mw1174.eqiad.wmnet" [1] => string(18)
        "mw1175.eqiad.wmnet"
    }["X-Powered-By"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(17)
        "HHVM/3.3.0-static" [1] => string(17)
        "HHVM/3.3.0-static"
    }["Location"] => string(26)
    "https://www.wikipedia.org/" ["Cache-Control"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(15)
        "max-age=2592000" [1] => string(45)
        "s-maxage=86400, must-revalidate, max-age=3600"
    }["Expires"] => string(29)
    "Wed, 21 Dec 2016 14:55:26 GMT" ["Vary"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(34)
        "X-Forwarded-Proto, Accept-Encoding" [1] => string(15)
        "Accept-Encoding"
    }["X-Varnish"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(60)
        "252832401 234761536, 189834925 105479673, 503055844 58285403" [1] => string(57)
        "815608054 810788132, 143499750 28230570, 504104889 557059"
    }["Via"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(46)
        "1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4" [1] => string(46)
        "1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4"
    }["Age"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(6)
        "521357" [1] => string(5)
        "59119"
    }["X-Cache"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(41)
        "cp1053 hit/4, cp3032 hit/9, cp3030 hit/17" [1] => string(46)
        "cp1054 hit/8, cp3032 hit/33, cp3030 hit/531848"
    }["X-Cache-Status"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(3)
        "hit" [1] => string(3)
        "hit"
    }["Set-Cookie"] => array(4) {
        [0] => string(88)
        "WMF-Last-Access=27-Nov-2016;Path=/;HttpOnly;secure;Expires=Thu, 29 Dec 2016 12:00:00 GMT" [1] => string(76)
        "GeoIP=GB:WLS:Ammanford:51.79:-3.99:v4; Path=/; secure; Domain=.wikipedia.com" [2] => string(88)
        "WMF-Last-Access=27-Nov-2016;Path=/;HttpOnly;secure;Expires=Thu, 29 Dec 2016 12:00:00 GMT" [3] => string(76)
        "GeoIP=GB:WLS:Ammanford:51.79:-3.99:v4; Path=/; secure; Domain=.wikipedia.org"
    }["X-Analytics"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(19)
        "https=1;nocookies=1" [1] => string(19)
        "https=1;nocookies=1"
    }["X-Client-IP"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(13)
        "81.129.193.46" [1] => string(13)
        "81.129.193.46"
    }[1] => string(15)
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ["ETag"] => string(23)
    "W/"
    13 b64 - 541e8 ad5dab71 "" ["Last-Modified"] => string(29)
    "Tue, 22 Nov 2016 19:21:20 GMT" ["Backend-Timing"] => string(24)
    "D=213 t=1479943165198824" ["Strict-Transport-Security"] => string(44)
    "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" ["Accept-Ranges"] => string(5)
    "bytes"
}
```

Comment: This is such a weird problem. It started happening on one of my own servers and domains after a certificate update. I thought it was specific to my domain until I found this, and sure enough Wikipedia also fails. However, this only happens on one specific box, others (with different PHP versions) work fine. I'd really like to get to the bottom of this.